# Django in Chart.JS data not plotting properly

Tags: django, chart.js

I am building a line chart and the data is not plotting against the correct dates.

The Chart.js configuration is displayed below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const labels = [{% for date in dates %}'{{ date|date }}',{% endfor %}]
    
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{% for trial in trial_list %}

                {
                    label: '{{trial.behavior_name}}',
                    

                    data: '{{trial.frequency_input}}',
                    
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    tension: 0.4

                    
                }, {% endfor %}
            ] 
        }
        
    }); 
});
```

Here is the view function i am using:

```
def dashboard(request):
    # filter list of client sessions by selected client
    client_sessions = Client_Session.objects.filter(therapist=request.user)
    client = DashboardClientFilter(request.GET, queryset=client_sessions)
    client_sessions = client.qs

    #Create list of Trials across Client Sessions for the filtered client
    client_pks = client.qs.values_list('client_id',flat=True)
    trial_list = Trial.objects.filter(client_session__client_id__in=list(client_pks))
    #trial_list = trial_list.exclude(duration_input__isnull = False)
    trial_list = trial_list.order_by('client_session__session_date')
    print(trial_list)
    
    dates=[]
    for i in range(trial_list.count()) :
        if trial_list[i].client_session.session_date not in dates :
            dates.append(trial_list[i].client_session.session_date)

    
    trial_list_values = trial_list.values('behavior_name__name','frequency_input','duration_input','client_session__session_date')
    print('printing trial list values')
    print(trial_list_values)
   
    
    context = {'client_sessions':client_sessions, 'client':client, 'trial_list':trial_list, 'trial_list_values':trial_list_values,'dates':dates}
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

THe screenshot below illustrates the issue further. All my data points in the chart are plotting on July 13 when in reality they should be plotting across the other dates on the x axis.
[image]

Comment: The way you build your `dates` array in python seems to indicate that your `trial_list` is not structured as you'd expect. For each date you seem to have only one `frequency_input` value, which explains why you have just one point in each dataset. The part where you group all `frequency_input` values that correspond to the same date seems to be missing.